# can't configure Intellij IDEA with jira svn branches

Tags: svn, version-control, intellij-idea

I've checked out my repository trunk. this works, and I can commit changes to the trunk.
My repository trunk url is:

```
https://foo.jira.com/svn/PROJECTNAME/trunk
```

We're also using multiple branches, so I want to configure them in Intellij Idea. The branches URL is:

```
https://foo.jira.com/svn/PROJECTNAME/branches
```

In the "Configure Subversion Branches"-dialog, I hit the "+"-button and this error pops up:

```
svn: E170001: OPTIONS of '/svn': 403 Forbidden (https://foo.jira.com)
```

I have full rights on the PROJECTNAME-project, but it seems like svn uses the svn folder as root, although https://foo.jira.com/svn/PROJECTNAME is set as project root.

Can anyone help me with this?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [known bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-100308). Workaround is to type the branch URL manually instead of browsing.

Answer (score 0):

As per above :
Add the following parameter to the JVM (edited the service in regedit):

```
-Dsvnkit.http.methods=Basic,Digest,Negotiate,NTLM
```

To find the service in regedit, just lookup the Service name in services.msc 
(e.g. JIRA031011191852) and search for it in regedit.

Also, if using SSL be sure it's enabled in the JVM input arguments.

```
-Dsvnkit.http.sslProtocols=SSLv3
```

Worked for me.